# In an n-character string of numbers ascending by 1, "1234567...n" how many arrangements have only the even (or odd) digits in their original places?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

So for example I have "123456789" and I need to find how many arrangements there are where only the even digits are in their original places. Would it be correct to simply take the remaining "1 3 5 7 9" and do a permutation, P(5,5)?

Comment: No, $P(5,5)$ includes some instances where some odd numbers are in their correct places. You need to count “derangements.” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement?wprov=sfti1

Comment: Ah, wouldn't it just be d_5? I will feel so dumb if that's all it is.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by $d_5,$ but if it’s not something to feel dumb about. Wikipedia calls the number $!5.$

Comment: Sorry, forgot that teachers' formatting is not always be consistent with universal formatting. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Nathan: Yes, if $d_5$ is the number of derangements of $1,2,3,4,5$; other common notations are $D_5$ and $!5$.